# Why am I getting errors relating to strip() when I'm not using it? (Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working through a scraping task in Python using BeautifulSoup and am getting some strange errors.  It's mentioning strip, which I'm not using, but I'm guessing might be related to the processes of BSoup?

In the task I'm trying to go to the original url, find the 18th link, click that link 7 times, and then return the name result for the 18th link on the 7th page.  I'm trying to use a function to get the href from the 18th link, then adjust the global variable to recurse through with a different url each time.  Any advice on what I'm missing would be really helpful.  I'll list the code and errors:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

nameList = []
urlToUse = "http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Basile.html"

def linkOpen():
    global urlToUse
    html = urllib.urlopen(urlToUse)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    tags = soup("li")
    count = 0
    for tag in tags:
        if count == 17:
            tagUrl = re.findall('href="([^ ]+)"', str(tag))
            nameList.append(tagUrl)
            urlToUse = tagUrl
            count = count + 1
        else:
            count = count + 1
            continue

bigCount = 0
while bigCount < 9:
    linkOpen()
    bigCount = bigCount + 1

print nameList[8]
```

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assignmentLinkScrape.py", line 26, in <module>
    linkOpen()
  File "assignmentLinkScrape.py", line 10, in linkOpen
    html = urllib.urlopen(urlToUse)
  File         

"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)   File 
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 185, in open
    fullurl = unwrap(toBytes(fullurl))   File
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1075, in unwrap
        url = url.strip() AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.findall()` returns *a list of matches*. `urlToUse` is a list and you are trying to pass it to `urlopen()` which expects a URL string instead.

Comment: I've changed to re.search and still getting errors.  When I use str(tag) I get errors relating to there being no strip attribute as well.  `AttributeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object has no attribute 'strip`

Comment: @McLeodx `re.search` doesn't return a string, it returns a `MatchObject`.  Read the [specification](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects).

Answer (score 2):

*Alexce* has explained your error but you don't need a regex at all, you just want to get the 18th li tag and extract the href from the anchor tag inside that, you can use *find* with *find_all*:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Basile.html").content,"lxml")

url = soup.find("ul").find_all("li", limit=18)[-1].a["href"]
```

Or use a css selector:

```
url = soup.select_one("ul li:nth-of-type(18) a")["href"]
```

So to get the name after visiting the url seven times, put the logic in a function, visit the intial url then visit and extract the anchor seven times, then on the last visit just extract the text from the anchor:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Basile.html").content,"lxml")

def get_nth(n, soup):
    return soup.select_one("ul li:nth-of-type({}) a".format(n))

start = get_nth(18, soup)
for _ in range(7):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(start["href"]).content,"html.parser")
    start = get_nth(18, soup)
print(start.text)
```